# Keep data highlighted (selected) in a DataGridView after filtering the BindingSource

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a DataTable that is attached to a DataGridView via BindingSource.
My grid (and data) are dynamic - the BindingSource has a filter rule and every second, one value is changed and the filter is applied on its parent row. For example:

for a table:

```
id    name    status
--    ----    ------
100   aaaa    false
200   bbbb    false
300   cccc    false
```

and a filter rule:

```
"status = false"
```

after changing status=true to id number 200 and refreshing the DataGridView, the new shown table is:

```
id    name    status
--    ----    ------
100   aaaa    false
300   cccc    false
```

Now, let's say id 300 is at row 300 in the DataTable. If I want it to be the first displayed row, I can use DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 300, but after applying the filter, it will no longer be at row #300 in the DataGrid, it will be at row #299 since id 200 was filtered out.
How can I keep the row with id 300 to be the first row shown in the DataGridView?

Comment: you could add a column with a datetime - then sort desc

Comment: The data should be ordered by id

Comment: After the filter is applied… how would you know “which” row to assign as the top row? In other words… using your example, once the filter is applied, how did you know that 300 was the row that you wanted to be displayed first? I assume you could loop through the grid and “find” which grid row 300 is on then set it as the first row in the grid.